Insert data from excel to DB table & skip column if doesn't exist
I'm using the following INSERT statement to extract numeric data from an excel file and make it appear in a database table. Both excel column names and those in the DB table are matching...
However, I need to make the below statement more flexible:
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE] ([COLUMNA], [COLUMNB], [COLUMNC], [COLUMND], [COLUMNE])
    SELECT A.[COLUMNA], TRY_CAST(A.[COLUMNB] AS INT), TRY_CAST(A.[COLUMNC] AS INT), TRY_CAST(A.[COLUMND] AS INT), TRY_CAST(A.[COLUMNE] AS INT) 
    FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                     'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Temp\uploadfile.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
                     'select * from [Sheet$]') AS A;

As to avoid such errors in logs if one or more columns in the Excel file are missing. Idea is to only match those columns that exist in the Excel file.

Invalid column name 'COLUMNC'


Add an appropiate tag from your rdbms to your question.

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @columns = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME([COLUMN_NAME]), ', ')
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Temp\uploadfile.xlsx;HDR=YES',
                'SELECT [COLUMN_NAME] FROM [Sheet$] WHERE [COLUMN_NAME] IS NOT NULL');

SET @sql = '
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE] (' + @columns + ')
    SELECT ' + @columns + '
    FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
                    ''Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Temp\uploadfile.xlsx;HDR=YES'',
                    ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet$]'') AS A;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

Do this maybe
Instead of selecting all columns (SELECT *), explicitly select columns you need (SELECT [COLUMNA], [COLUMNB], [COLUMNC], [COLUMND], [COLUMNE]). This ensures that only these specific columns are fetched from the Excel file.

Thanks for your suggestion! However, I'm getting the following error when executing above: The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" supplied invalid metadata for column "COLUMN_NAME". The data type is not supported. What is the purpose of COLUMN_NAME in this case if there can be [COLUMNA], [COLUMNB], [COLUMNC], [COLUMND] and/or [COLUMNE] present per spreadsheet? Please advise.

(You are likely trying to do this for SQL server.)
I wouldn't suggest using Openrowset.
Have a look at SqlBulkCopy class and you could do this more easily with that using C# (or maybe you would want to use VB).
However, even with Openrowset you could do it easier if you are selecting into a new table. ie:
SELECT *
 into #someNewTable
    FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                     'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Temp\uploadfile.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
                     'select * from [Sheet$]') AS A;

